# Will "Hello Elementor" automatically convert SCSS to CSS

Tags: wordpress, sass, gruntjs, themes, elementor

I've just started using the WordPress page builder "Elementor" and have decided to move from "Genesis" to their own theme called "[Hello Elementor](https://github.com/elementor/elementor-hello-theme)". However, their theme uses SCSS and GruntJS.

On their documentation, they've included a custom.scss for all the custom styling. But when you add anything to this via WordPress, nothing happens. I know I could download the theme and use Visual Studio Code to make changes and use a sass compiler to automatically compile this for me, but it would require me to constantly upload files via FTP. Ideally, I would like to stay away from this.

Is there something I am missing? Or something I could do for WordPress to automatically compile this for me?

Edit:
If anyone has any recommendations of other themes to use with Elementor, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

They removed this option in Hello Elementor. You can no longer integrate custom scss. And I don't know since which version it's not present anymore, considering that I've tried the latest two ones and none of them seemed to accept the scss custom file.
However, you can check the answer they gave me a few days ago on the Hello Elementor GitHub page, if you want.
https://github.com/elementor/hello-theme/issues/85